# Encryption Using Classic Permutation

Tags: java, encryption, permutation

```
public class Encryption {
private static final int[] encrypt = {2, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0};
private static final int[] decrypt = new int[8];
private static final int minLength = 10;

String encrypt (String password)    {
    if(password.length()<minLength) {
        return password;
    }   else {
        char[] encrypt = password.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i++)    {
            encrypt[i] = (char) (encrypt[i]);
        }
        return String.valueOf(encrypt);
    }
}

String decrypt (String password)    {
    if (password.length()<minLength)    {
        return password;
    }   else {
        char[] decrypt = password.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length; i++) {
            decrypt[i] = (char) (decrypt[i]);
        }
        return String.valueOf(decrypt);
    }
}

boolean isValidLength (String password) {
    if (password.length()<minLength)    {
        return true;

    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

int getMinLength(){
    return minLength;
    }
 }
```

Suppose to encrypt my password (Driver hasn't been made yet), but not sure if I used my variables (encrypt and decrypt) correctly.  The Encrypt and Decrypt variables are so that the password changes index's to whatever the user types in, and also don't know, but am suppose to use the inverse purmutation method somewhere, but not sure where? Any help? Need someone to tell me if my program is way off, or is close.

Comment: Any chance you can step back, take a *deep* breath, and completely re-write that paragraph of yours?

Comment: Also take some time to ensure the formatting of your code works with SO.  Eliminate the excess whitespace (1 blank line is enough) and ensure the indentation displays correctly.  We want to help, but make it *easy* for us. :-)

Comment: Really all i'm wondering is if I can go on and write my driver. Is this program going to encrypt my password and then decrypt it properly.  For some reason I have that the variable encryption and decryption not being used and i'm not sure how and where to put it in my program so that is rearranges my password and then arranges it back properly...

Comment: Sorry about that [: I thought it would be easier for ya to read, but i'm new to this site, thanks for the fill in (;

Comment: "Will it encrypt and decrypt properly"--define "properly". It has an encrypt and decrypt function; those would be called wherever you need to perform one of those operations. But its correctness can be verified by testing it--have you?

Comment: No, but eclipse states that... the value of the field Encryption.encrypt and Encryption.decrypt has not been used.  I'll test it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encryption Program Changing Indexes of Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573760/encryption-program-changing-indexes-of-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning -- which is a *good warning* -- is because of [*shadowing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

The line:

```
char[] encrypt = password.toCharArray();
```

Causes the [static] *member variable* [which is also] called `encrypt` to be shadowed within that method. Thus **the "permutation values" are never used and the algorithm used will horribly break**. (It will break horribly because the "permutation values" are not the same on encrypt and decrypt. There is another issue with the decrypt algorithm, as it doest even use the [same] "permutation values", but that's another thing to work through.)

Solutions:

1. Use better/different names (say `encryptionKey` for the permutations).
2. Explicitly use `Encryption.encrypt` to refer to the [static] *member variable*.

And, of course, review the algorithm. There is no need for `Encryption.decrypt` and keeping it there will allow other errors to be introduced.

Happy coding.