# Encryption Program Changing Indexes of Strings

Tags: java, permutation

```
public class Encryption {
private static final int[] encrypt = {2, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0};
private static final int[] decrypt = new int[8];
private static final int minLength = 10;

String encrypt (String password)    {
    if(password.length()<minLength) {
        return password;

    }   else {
        char[] arrayEncrypted = password.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length; i++)    {
            arrayEncrypted[i] = (char) (arrayEncrypted[i]);

            }
            return String.valueOf(arrayEncrypted);

    }
}

String decrypt (String password)    {
    if (password.length()<minLength)    {
        return password;

    }   else {
        char[] arrayDecrypted = password.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDecrypted.length; i++) {
            arrayDecrypted[i] = (char) (arrayDecrypted[i]);
        }
        return String.valueOf(arrayDecrypted);
    }
}

boolean isValidLength (String password) {
    if (password.length()<minLength)    {
        return true;

    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

int getMinLength(){
    return minLength;
}

}
```

This program is suppose to use a classic permutation function to encrypt data. The encryption function to be used in the encryption class is only(2, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0).

Each character in the password is moved to a new index according to the permutation.  Since 2 is immediately followed by 9 in the permutation, the character at index 2 of the password must be reassigned to index 9.  Similarly, the character in index 9 must be reassigned to index 3 and so on.  The last reassignment completes the cycle by placing the character originally at index 0 into index 2.

Just checking because my program is very off, and I need some help to put it back on track.  Below is a picture of what it is suppose to look like when compiled.

[image: Compiled]

Comment: He never told me to use them in the list.

Comment: The homework tag is officially deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at this line.

```
arrayEncrypted[i] = (char) (arrayEncrypted[i]);
```

Unless I'm totally misinterpreting it, what you're doing there is... actually, *absolutely nothing*. You're taking the character found at position `i` in the array, and placing it at position `i`. What you want to do is something like

```
encryptionResult[i] = (arrayEncrypted[encrypt[i]]);
```

as you're trying to *rearrange* the characters.

Comment: Should I keep encryptionResult as arrayEncrypted??

Comment: The thing is, if you use arrayEncrypted to store both the original string and the result, it may become garbed. Imagine, for example, that `encrypt` is `{1, 2, 0}` - cat would become atc. However, if you use arrayEncrypted to store both result and original string (i. e. you overwrite the original characters), the first character has changed by the time you arrive at that point in the string - you would get ata as a result.

Comment: Ahh yes, so exactly how would I go by changing that so it does work, because i can't change it without initializing encryptionResult. Example?

Comment: I could think of two ways to do this. **One**, you could just declare a second array - an empty array with the same size as `arrayEncrypted` that will hold the rearranged password - and not change `arrayEncrypted` at all. What I described above, essentially. **Two**, you could alternatively use the `charAt()` method to retrieve the characters from the original string. As in, `arrayEncrypted[i] = password.charAt(encrypt[i])`